# How to align the answer environment so that it has to look like Question Environment?

Tags: enumerate, exam, answers

I am using these code to generate my Question paper...

```
\documentclass[a4paper,addpoints]{exam}

\newbox\allanswers
\setbox\allanswers=\vbox{}
\def\qn{\question}

\newenvironment{answer}
{%
    \global\setbox\allanswers=\vbox\bgroup\large
    \unvbox\allanswers
}%
{%
    \bigbreak
    \egroup
}

\newcommand{\showallanswers}{{\begin{center}
\vspace{1cm}\large{\textbf{Class Test II(Test for Improvement)\\
Mathematics Foundation\\Answer Key\\
\hrule
%\\Sets and Relations, Matrices, Determinants \& \\Continuity and Differentiation
}}
\end{center}\par\unvbox\allanswers}}
% End Phil's answer

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question First Question First Question First Question First Question First Question First Question First Question First Question First Question 
\begin{answer}
\thequestion. Answer for the first question.  Answer for the first question.  Answer for the first question.  Answer for the first question.  Answer for the first question.  Answer for the first question.  Answer for the first question. 
\end{answer}

\question Second Question
\begin{answer}
\thequestion.  Answer for the second questionAnswer for the second questionAnswer for the second questionAnswer for the second questionAnswer for the second questionAnswer for the second questionAnswer for the second questionAnswer for the second question
\end{answer}
\end{questions}
\showallanswers
\end{document}
```

With these codes I am getting output like this.
[image]

### My Question:

Look at the Question and answer, Question environment is running like Enumerate environment,
but the answer environment is working like manual.
Means to say, I dont want the word under the numbering in the answers. It should be like Question environment.
Exaclty like this figure,
[image]

Comment: Have you considered using the option `answers` in the `\documentclass`, along with the command `\printanswers`? I believe that will maintain the overall formatting of the document and simplify everything. Consider referring to the manual given at http://www-math.mit.edu/~psh/exam/examdoc.pdf

Comment: I have defined this comments for Mulple choice Questions...Means it will give answers for that mcq's also in the printing answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want these answer typeset like enumerations then it is simplest to use `enumerate`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newbox\allanswers
\setbox\allanswers=\vbox{}

\newenvironment{answer}
{\global\setbox\allanswers=\vbox\bgroup\unvbox\allanswers
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0pt]\item[\thequestion.]\ignorespaces}
{\end{enumerate}\egroup}

\newcommand{\showallanswers}{\par\bigbreak
\begin{center}
  \large\bfseries
  Class Test II (Test for Improvement)\\
  Mathematics Foundation\\
  Answer Key\\[1ex]
  \hrule
\end{center}
\unvbox\allanswers}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question First Question.
  First Question.
  First Question.
  First Question.
  First Question.
  First Question.
  First Question.
  First Question.
  First Question.
\begin{answer}
  Answer for the first question.
  Answer for the first question.
  Answer for the first question.
  Answer for the first question.
  Answer for the first question.
  Answer for the first question.
  Answer for the first question.
\end{answer}

\question Second Question.
\begin{answer}
  Answer for the second question.
  Answer for the second question.
  Answer for the second question.
  Answer for the second question.
  Answer for the second question.
  Answer for the second question.
  Answer for the second question.
  Answer for the second question
\end{answer}
\end{questions}

\showallanswers
\end{document}
```

My main change to your code is that the start of an answer adds

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item[\thequestion.]
```

and the end adds the closing

```
\end{enumerate}
```

This way you don't have to add the question number yourself.  It turned out this gave a large left margin on the answers, to fix this I have loaded the `enumitem` and set `leftmargin=0pt` in the options to the list.  This is just easier than using the low level LaTeX commands.